# SQL UNION ALL problem after using UNION ALL more than 10 times

Tags: sql, vba, oledb, ms-access-2007, excel-2007

I'm getting a formatting problem if I use more than 10 UNION ALL statements in my VBA Code.

If I use 10 or less everything works great.

What I'm trying to do is combine 12 worksheets (Excel 2007).

I have a numerical column called SC that turns into string and date if I have more than 10 UNION ALL. If I try to use ROUND with more than 10 UNION ALL my last selection will change all the records by one unit.

I'm using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 as my provider and my connection string has worked for several things in my code so far.

Is there any limit for UNION ALL statements when using OLEDB?

Here is my code.

```
Dim StrOr As String
Dim i As Variant
Dim Cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset

For i = 1 To 12
    StrOr = StrOr & " " & "SELECT SC FROM [" & MonthName(i, True) & "$" & "] UNION ALL"
Next

StrOr = Left(StrOr, Len(StrOr) - 9) & ";"

Call GetADOCnt

Call ADORs
```

Comment: What are you trying to use the recordset for?

Comment: Set Rcst = New ADODB.Recordset <Line Break>
Rs.Open SQlString, Cn

Comment: Yes, but what are you going to do with the recordset? Attach it to a pivot table, a chart, or loop over it?

Comment: Right now I'm just copying the merged tables to another table. My goal was to group by the merged tables but I can't even get to that point because my recordset has this formatting problem. If I try I get a data type mismatch error for the GROUP BY (I don't get any error if I have 10 or less UNION ALL).

Comment: Hm...maybe the problem is the 11 or 12 data? Try 1 to 10 and 12. Skip 11.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: No. It's not. I have tried from i = 1 to 11 and from i = 2 to 12 and it works. I'm not getting any error message. I'm copying the recordset to a table. If I use more than 10 UNION ALL my records that are numbers turn into string for the first 11 months and for December they turn into date. I have tried to put January as the last month too but it didn't work.

Comment: From what you are describing, I believe you had something wrong with the cell formats between the sheets. This is usually a problem with Excel data. What you see is the formatted value. The command is trying to "union" different data types and is failing. Sometimes you can fix this by changing the affected cell's format. Sometimes, you have to "copy" and "paste special -> values" to get it working.

Comment: I have tried to change the formatting but it didn't help. I have three columns with data. The first column has dates and the other 2 have numbers. I've notice that if I add a column on the Dec worksheet or if I delete one of the columns that isn't the column SC the query works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: My bet is that the 11th sheet as bad data in it.... try making your UNION backwards (FOR i = 12 TO 1 STEP -1) to see if problems arise at the same point.

Answer (score 0):

If you're appending the UNION of the 12 worksheets, why not just use your loop to append each worksheet one at a time? You obviously don't need to de-dupe (you're using UNION ALL), so that seems like it would be an obvious solution to avoiding whatever problem is happening with your UNION'ed recordset.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but I believe they also what to GROUP BY.

Comment: I interpreted this differently: "I'm just copying the merged tables to another table. My goal was to group by the merged tables". That seems to say GROUP BY after the append, but you may be right that he was trying to do it in one go. If the UNION doesn't work, perhaps he could use a staging table as the GROUP BY source. But ultimately, if your surmise about the reason for the error is correct, it's going to encounter the error even appending one-by-one, and changing to that approach would make it easier to diagnose which spreadsheet is the problem child and address it individually.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to union all the tables to do a group by after that.

Comment: If you're doing the GROUP BY on the table instead of on the UNION SQL, then changing to append one worksheet at a time should help you resolve the problem and not change the results at all.

Comment: How can I append one worksheet at a time and then do the GROUP BY?

Comment: Inside your loop, instead of writing a SQL UNION, write a SQL INSERT and execute each one in each repetition of the loop. Then once the loop finishes, you'll have all your data in the table and can then GROUP BY on the appended table data.

Comment: I tried StrOr = "INSERT INTO [" & "Sheet1" & "$" & "] SELECT * FROM [" & "Jan" & "$" & "];" And I got the following error (Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.)

Comment: Does the SELECT part work by itself, without the INSERT part?

Comment: Then the problem is in the SQL for the INSERT and you'll have to troubleshoot that to figure out what the problem is. I don't know the table and field names of your destination table, so can't really offer any specific advice.